# Control action breadcrumbs

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

### I'm interested to know if there is any way to control breadcrumbs completely.

For example remove `Projects` or add `Custom Breadcrumb` between Project and Tasks and etc.

[image]

I've tried *(from Odoo forum pages)*

```
'clear_breadcrumb': True
```

But it doesn't works at all. And if it would worked it's not my question anyway.

Also I've also searched keywords in odoo source but I found nothing. It seems breadcrumbs are not controllable with current API. Now I'm trying to find a way to control them by jQuery but nothing promising yet.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with breadcrumbs? And which version of odoo are you using ?

Comment: Hi George, I tagged odoo-8 and odoo-9, it doesn't matters for both version it would be same imho. I've not any specific task for breadcrumbs I'm just interested if its controllable for developer, for many situations for example it would be better if we hide breadcrumbs and also its also very interesting if we can edit breadcrumbs as we want using some standard ways. I think the obvious method is to using jquery and edit breadcrumbs but I don't like this solution and I asked myself maybe there is some ways to control them using actions or context

Comment: Do you solve this problem? I have the same. Also trying the same methods as 'clear_breadcrumbs': true but nothing happens..

Comment: hi there, 'clear_breadcrumbs' actually works and clears all the breadcrumbs but there is not any controlling mechanism to control breadcrumbs as you want. that feels very bad... there is not any solution to control them

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you use it from python code like:             return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'name': _('Order'),
                'res_model': 'purchase.request',
                'res_id': data.get('order_id'),
                'view_type': 'form',
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'target': 'current',
                'clear_breadcrumbs': true,
                'nodestroy': True, }

Comment: I use it from my python code in function like this and nothing happens..

Comment: in javascript side it works,in js you are doing like this `do_action(action, option)` where options could have this value like this: `var options = {'clear_breadcrumbs': true}`

Comment: Do you mean extend action_manager.js do_action? I need to use that only for one model because breadcrumbs there are duplicated. And only one way what to do is to hide them on specific model if it is possible.